# Extending Codomain of Function to Show Existence of Open Sets

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

I have a potentially strange question. I am trying to prove something along the lines of showing the existence of open, disjoint supersets $U, V$ of respectively closed, disjoint sets $A, B$ st.  $A, B \subseteq M$ for some metric space $M$. In doing so, I have constructed a continuous function $f(x) : M \to [0,1] \ $ s.t. $f(x) = 0$ for any $x \in A$ and $f(x) = 1$ for any $x \in B$. What I want to do is use the fact that $f[A] \subseteq (-1/2, 1/2) \ $ and $f[B] \subseteq (1/2, 3/2) \ $ to show that $U = f^{-1}(-1/2, 1/2) \ $ and $V = f^{-1}(1/2, 3/2) \ $ work as the desired open supersets of $A$ and $B$. The fact that they are open follows from continuity of $f$ and the fact that they are supersets is not difficult to see either.

My question is, is it okay to just "extend" the codomain of the function $f$ to be able to look at open intervals (-1/2, 1/2) and (1/2, 3/2) even though I know the function actually maps to $[0,1]$? It is a strange thing to do but I see no reason we shouldn't be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is fine. There are various ways of looking at this: the way that is closest to what you are saying is that the inclusion $i: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, so your argument applies just as well to the continuous function $i \circ f$.

Another, arguably better/more illuminating way to look at it is to take $[0,1]$ as a metric space/topological space in its own right. In this space, the set $[0, 1/2)$ is actually *open*, unlike in the real numbers. If we take $[0,1]$ as a metric space, then you'll note that $[0,1/2)$ is $D_{1/2}(0)$, the open ball of radius $1/2$ around 0. If we take $[0,1]$ as a topological subspace of $\mathbb R$, then its open sets are the intersections of $[0,1]$ with open sets of $\mathbb R$, and $[0,1] \cap (-1/2, 1/2) = [0,1/2)$ is thus open in $[0,1]$.

(Just as a side note, in case you're not aware, since you haven't used the term: you are proving that every metric space is a [normal topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space), in case you want to know more about the property.)

Comment: Both of your answers are incredibly illuminating. I completely forgot that $[0,1]$ is a metric space in its own right. Also thank you for naming the property! I was trying to learn more about its importance.